# Getting [fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-archVFPv3-D32' in 'p2'] error while compiling win8 app

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

Sometimes I getting this error:

fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-archVFPv3-D32' in 'p2'

Visual Studio 2013, Windows Store app (c++ and c# projects).

It seems that full rebuild resolve this problem - until next time.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you compiling to LocalMachine or RemoteMachine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this problem too. And my mistake was:

1) Using .lib file which compiled how a Debug and i use him in Release mode app

In general, my app was get old .lib with old parameters from error link.

I updated parameter in **Configuration Properties** -> **Linker** -> **General** -> **Additional Library Directories** and all works at fine.

Answer (score 4):

This can also occur when you have changed the compiler and the static libs that you are linking to are compiled using a different compiler. E.g. different versions of MSVC compilers.